# (rolling) n-weekly average

Tags: probability-or-statistics, finance

I have the data of the SPX index weekly

`dataweekly=FinancialData["^SPX", "OHLCV", {{2010, 7, 1}, Today, "Week"}]["Path"][[All, 2]];`

and I calculate the arithmetic returns:

`datapercweekly=100*(dataweekly[[All, 4]] - dataweekly[[All, 1]])/dataweekly[[All, 1]];`

Obviously, this corresponds to individual weeks.
I am looking for a method to calculate the arithmetic returns for every (rolling) n weeks (eg n=6).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look at `Fold` & `Table`.  I'll give this some thought this weekend.  You may also want to look in the documentation at `FinancialIndicators`.  Not certain how this set of dressed up pseudo science got into Mathematica.  Most of these indicators require extraordinary and completely undisclosed assumptions (e.g. markets revert to a mean and behave like normal distributions) indefensible in the real world. The documentation has no discussion of the underlying/implied assumptions. Ethically, I  advise avoiding them, but they exist and can produce pretty graphics.  Sorry if this seems like a rant,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(* Get the weekly closing prices *)
dataweekly = FinancialData["^SPX", "Close", {{2010, 7, 1}, Today, "Week"}];

(* 6 week rolling weekly return *)
rolling = MovingMap[100*(Last[#]/First[#] - 1) &, dataweekly, {6, "Week"}];
DateListPlot[rolling]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not certain what your really want to do, but maybe the following will spark some ideas.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{dw, dpw},
  dw = dataweekly[[All, 4]];
  dpw = datapercweekly;
  Grid[{
    {ListLinePlot[dw, ImageSize -> 350],
     ListLinePlot[dpw, ImageSize -> 350]},
    {ListLinePlot[MovingAverage[dw, n], ImageSize -> 350],
     ListLinePlot[MovingAverage[dpw, n], ImageSize -> 350]}},
   Spacings -> 3]],
 {n, 1, 6, 1}]
```

[image]